# Magento import error

Tags: magento-1.9, import, sku

I am importing a large csv file(about 5.5 MB). Whenever I try to import it gives error

```
Product with specified super products SKU not found in rows
```

I have googled this issue and found that it is something related to configurable products.
But I was unable to find exact solution for this. 
Please help.

**EDIT**

Below is the screen shot of first product in my CSV.
[image]

And the following screen shot have the products that just came after first product
[image]

Comment: I think this is to do with the order of products in the csv. Make sure that the parent product is first in the csv.

Comment: If this doesn't help, could you post an excerpt of your csv file with one configurable and all assigned simple products?

Comment: Hello David. By parent did you mean configurable product. If is so they already in parent child order. I mean first configurable product comes then its associated products.

Comment: Hey Andreas, please see my edit.

Comment: Same problem here. Even exporting from Magento and then trying to import the same CSV back into the system can produce this error.

Answer (score 3):

I had the same error. I have changed the order of products in the `CSV` file. I have put the associated products (simple products) first and then the configurable product and the problem was solved!

Comment: Thanks! Why does Magento export like this?

Comment: Didn't work for me though. I have by default first associated products and then the configurable one, in the csv, for each group of configurable product and its associated products. Still, the error shows.

Answer (score 0):

It's old, but I struggled over it multiple times. :-)

To solve this Problem I manipulated the `_prepareEntityCollection of Mage_ImportExport_Model_Export_Entity_Abstract`

in an own module Extension of `Mage_ImportExport_Model_Export_Entity_Product`

like this:

```
 /**
 * Rewrite of Mage_ImportExport_Model_Export_Entity_Abstract::_prepareEntityCollection
 * for the purpose of getting the configurable products to the end of CSV file:
 *
 * Problem was:https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/44368/magento-import-error
 *
 * Apply filter to collection and add not skipped attributes to select.
 *
 * @param Mage_Eav_Model_Entity_Collection_Abstract $rCollection
 * @return Mage_Eav_Model_Entity_Collection_Abstract
 */
protected function _prepareEntityCollection(Mage_Eav_Model_Entity_Collection_Abstract $oCollection)
{
    $rCollection= parent::_prepareEntityCollection($oCollection);
    $rCollection->addAttributeToSort('type_id', Mage_Eav_Model_Entity_Collection_Abstract::SORT_ORDER_DESC);
    return $rCollection;
}
```